# TwythonStreamer accents encoding? - unable to decode response, not valid JSON, with code 200

Tags: python, json, twitter, stream, twython

I started playing recently with Twython and the twitter API. The auth was a bit cumbersome to deal with but it's now working perfectly with a little Bottle webserver included in my script.

I'm trying to do something very simple:  track a hashtag with the streaming filter API.
It seemed to work well at first but now I can see many errors in my log:

```
Error!
200 Unable to decode response, not valid JSON
```

It happens only on part of the tweets. I thought it could be linked to coordinates, but that's not it. I just tested and it seems to be caused by accents (éèêàâ...) encoding issues.

How can I fix this?

My streamer code is very basic:

```
class QMLStreamer(TwythonStreamer):
    def on_success(self, data):
        if 'text' in data:
            if 'coordinates' in data and data['coordinates'] and 'coordinates' in data['coordinates']:
                tweetlog("[%s](%s) - %s" % (data['created_at'], data['coordinates']['coordinates'], data['text'].encode('utf-8')))
            else:
                tweetlog("[%s] - %s" % (data['created_at'], data['text'].encode('utf-8')))

    def on_error(self, status_code, data):
        print colored('Error !', 'red', attrs=['bold'])
        print status_code, data
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens in your code. You shouldn't be using `.encode()` here.

It is a bit counter-intuitive, but `on_error()` will be called if `on_success()` raised an exception, which is probably what happens here (a `UnicodeDecodeError`). That's why you're seeing an error code 200 ("HTTP Ok").

Twython is returning data as unicode objects, so you can just do:

`print(u"[%s](%s) - %s" % (data['created_at'], data['coordinates']['coordinates'], data['text']))`

You should probably add your own try...except block in `on_success()` for further debugging.

Also, I'm not sure what your `tweetlog()` function does, but be aware if you are on Windows that `print()` might have issues writing some codepoints as it will try to convert to the terminal's codepage.

Comment: I sent out a [pull request](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/pull/271) about the error masking issue.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. I just figured that out by myself and came to post the solution, but you were faster it seems.

I removed the encoding form that line you quoted, to keep it unicode, and added it in my printing / logging functions.

It now works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

No a perfect answer but you can try printing a normalized version of the text using unicodedata:

```
import unicodedata
```

...

```
tweetlog("[%s](%s) - %s" % (data['created_at'], data['coordinates']['coordinates'], unicodedata.normalize('NFD',data['text']).encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
```

Comment: The thing is JSON decoding is happening within TwythonStreamer, which makes it call `on_error` directly instead of `on_success` when it goes banana...

So this line you refer to is never called when the error comes up.